# Is it faster to find if a character is a letter, or parse and integer?

Tags: c#, char, int

**Question 1:**

I am taking text files and formatting them into the correct format to use their data. The problem is that if a line starts with a number, it actually should be in the first line above it with a name ( or a set of letters). So I want to know if it is faster to test the first char in the line to see if it is an int by parsing it and seeing if that doesn't fail, or do char.IsLetter to see if it is an alphabetic character?  I assume there is overhead in a failed parse, even surrounded in a try, and most of the lines do start with a letter, so I am not sure about the speed.

**Question 2:**

if char.IsLetter is faster, what would be the easiest way to handle blank character ("") that appear at the beginning of some lines? I know that int.Parse handles them, so it is harder to figure out how to handle if thats the first character.

Comment: Compared to the time taken to read text from a file the overhead of any of these (TryParse or IsDigit etc) is likely to be irrelevant. Write the code that is simplest and easiest to maintain. If you run in to serious performance issues profile your code to find hotspots and try other approaches then.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. There is no such thing as a blank character. Please show some example input and output. And are you sure you're looking for the "fastest" way, did you determine this part of your code to be the bottleneck?

Comment: @CodeCaster I couldn't describe it to you. when i log it, that character simply shows up to be a blank.. i have tested in the code for  spaces such as " ", but that does not fix the problem and still out buts a simple blank line. when i test for "" with no spaces and log it, thats what shows up in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for me is:

```
if(Char.IsDigit(str.TrimStart(' ').FirstOrDefault()))
{


}
```

The overhead of `try...catch` is more than the above approach.

I guess that best way to determine that is so write the two methods and wrap the call with a **Stopwatch** to measure the time of each. I don't think the difference is significant.